# Username/password Authentication Rules in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

Currently, when a user logs into my Laravel app I use the following rules...

```
// Validation rules
$rules = array(
    'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
    'password' => 'required'
);
```

What I'm looking for is a validation rule for checking the password against the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users):

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password))) {
    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
```

Example:

```
$userdata = array(
    'email'    => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Input::get('password')
);

$rules = array(
    'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
    'password' => 'required'
);

// Validate the inputs.
$validator = Validator::make($userdata, $rules);

// Check if the form validates with success.
if ($validator->passes()) {
    // Try to log the user in.
    if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
        // Redirect to homepage
        return Redirect::to('')->with('success', 'You have logged in successfully');
    } else {
        // Redirect to the login page.
        return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors(array('password' => 'Password invalid'))->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Valery Viktorovsky Your example kind of confused me. Where is the `email` field which you supposed to validate? Why you use the `username` field input twice as an `id`? Why you need to `unset` the `username` since you don't even validate it at first thus you don't even need it? Why you pass anything different than the validator object in your `withErrors` method?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed typo. $userdata must be $userdata = array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password'));

'Auth::attempt' requires array with 2 elements: column name corresponds to a "username" and password.

Comment: @ValeryViktorovsky Ok now it makes more sense, but still you don't need the `username` input since you don't use it and I think it's incorrect to pass an array as an argument in the `withErrors` method.

Comment: @yannishristofakis This is just example, so I don't included custom username validation. If it confuses you I deleted username related code.

I think you should view laravel code (withErrors method) https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php#L109. 
withErrors method uses MessageBag, which require array as param (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.php#L30)